# sequelize.showAllTables is not a function

Tags: sequelize.js

refering to that [docu](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html) part which says there is a function -and it is there- named `showAllSchemas`

I implemented it with my SQLite3 DB like this:

```
function showTables () {
  sequelize.showAllTables().then(result => console.log(result))
}
```

But by executing it says

```
TypeError: sequelize.showAllTables is not a function
```

I am confused. Any idea?

btw: In general I have this solution as well which works but it is not exactly what I want

```
  sequelize.query('select name from sqlite_master where type=\'table\'').then(function (rows) {
    console.log(rows)
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access [`showAllTables`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v5.7.4/lib/query-interface.js#L417) method by invoking it on the [`queryInterface`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v5.7.4/lib/sequelize.js#L311).

This is the queryInterface property of the instance of `Sequelize` that was created.

```
async function showTables() {
  await tables = sequelize
    .getQueryInterface()
    .showAllTables()

  console.log(tables)
}
```